# Fastest way to sort a vector of std::pair<int,int>

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a text file containing 1 000 000 lines of pairs of int like so :

```
8537 8433
6032 2674
2826 2205
5030 8079
8773 7981
7215 947
2875 89
2408 1305
```

which are stored in a `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>`.

I have to program an algorithm that sorts a list of pairs [(c1, d1), (c2, d2), . . . , (cn, dn)]. To compare two pairs (ci, di) and (cj, dj ), I just have to compare the first element of each pair, i.e. compare ci with cj . Thus the pair (2, 5) comes before the pair (3, 0) because 2 < 3 and the pair (3, 2) is similar to the pair (3, 10) because 3 = 3. In the case of two similar pairs, we must preserve the order of appearance in the original list. The list [(2, 7), (1, 8), (2, 3), (1, 6)], once sorted, becomes [(1, 8), (1, 6), (2, 7), (2, 3)]. The pair (1, 8) comes before the pair (1, 6) since these two pairs are comparable and (1, 8) comes before (1, 6) in the original list.

The goal of the assignment is to implement a sorting algorithm for this data structure myself and compare the execution time of my implementation with the execution time of stable_sort.

Currently, I've opted to insert each pair at the right index in a sorted vector.

```
void enumerationSort(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> &list) {
    assert(!list.empty());

    if (list.size() == 1) {
        return;
    }

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> temp = {list[0]};
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        temp.insert(std::upper_bound(temp.begin(), temp.end(), list[i]), list[i]);
    }

    list = temp;
}
```

Like I said, I have to compare the execution time of my custom sorting function with the `std::stable_sort` function, which I have already programmed like so :

```
bool comparison(const std::pair<int, int> &a, const std::pair<int, int> &b) {
    return a.first < b.first;
}

void stableSort(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> &list) {
    std::stable_sort(list.begin(), list.end(), comparison);
}
```

but currently, the execution time of my sorting algorithm is **nowhere near** the execution time of the `std::stable_sort`.

I am testing the execution time of each functions with code resembling to this :

```
void process_data(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> &list, int step, std::string filename, bool stable_sort) {
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    if (stable_sort) {
        stableSort(liste);
    } else {
        enumerationSort(liste);
    }
    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> ms_double = stop - start;

    // Saves the execution time in a txt file so that I can use matplotlib to plot a 
    // graph of both function's execution time
    save_execution_time(ms_double.count(), step, filename); 
}
```

What would be the best way to sort the vector of pair?

Comment: Your algorithm is super naive and it's quite normal that its performance is very poor. Google this: _shlemiel the painter's algorithm_

Comment: @Federico The goal of the assignment is to implement a sorting algorithm for this data structure myself and compare the execution time of my implementation with the execution time of stable_sort.

Comment: @Math that information belongs into the question.

Comment: @Math I suggest you google _"stable sort algorithm"_

Comment: @Jabberwocky Noted. Also edited my question with the explanation for my assignment

Answer (score 0):

Use a bucket sort. Based on your data set, you'd only have to iterate through the list 4 times.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort